# tidyr::spread() function throws an error

Tags: r, syntax-error, spread

I try to use gather and spread functions in tidyverse package, but it throws an error in spread function

library(caret)

```
dataset<-iris

# gather function is to convert wide data to long data

dataset_gather<-dataset %>% tidyr::gather(key=Type,value = Values,1:4)

head(dataset_gather)

# spead is the opposite of gather
```

*This code below throws an error like this Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows*

```
dataset_spead<- dataset_gather%>%tidyr::spread(key = Type,value = Values)
```

Comment: After using `gather` you don't have a unique identifier, and so you can't use `spread` on such a dataframe

Comment: Maybe if you include some of the actual data you can working with and an example of how you want it to look it'll be more helpful

Comment: Add a row identifier to the wide form, e.g. `iris %>% mutate(i = row_number()) %>% gather(var, val, -i) %>% spread(var, val)`

Comment: Thanks @alistaire for your comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added later: Sorry @alistaire, only saw your comment on the original post after posting this response.

As far as I understand `Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows...`, it occurs when you have values with the same identifier. For example in the original 'iris' dataset, the first five rows of *Species = setosa* all have a *Petal.Width* of 0.2, and three rows of `Petal.Length` have values of 1.4. Gathering those data isn't an issue, but when you try spread them, the function doesn't know what belongs to what. That is, which 0.2 *Petal.Width* and 1.4 *Petal.Length* belongs to which row of *setosa*.

The (tidyverse) solution I use in those circumstances is to create a unique marker for each row of data at the gather stage so that the function can keep track which duplicate data belong to which rows when you want to spread again. See example below:

```r
# Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

# Get data
dataset <- iris

# View dataset
head(dataset)
#>   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
#> 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
#> 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
#> 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
#> 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

# Gather data
dataset_gathered <- dataset %>% 
    # Create a unique identifier for each row 
    mutate(marker = row_number(Species)) %>%
    # Gather the data
    gather(key = Type, value = Values, 1:4)

# View gathered data
head(dataset_gathered)
#>   Species marker         Type Values
#> 1  setosa      1 Sepal.Length    5.1
#> 2  setosa      2 Sepal.Length    4.9
#> 3  setosa      3 Sepal.Length    4.7
#> 4  setosa      4 Sepal.Length    4.6
#> 5  setosa      5 Sepal.Length    5.0
#> 6  setosa      6 Sepal.Length    5.4

# Spread it out again
dataset_spread <- dataset_gathered %>%
    # Group the data by the marker
    group_by(marker) %>%
    # Spread it out again
    spread(key = Type, value = Values) %>%
    # Not essential, but remove marker
    ungroup() %>%
    select(-marker)

# View spread data
head(dataset_spread)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   Species Petal.Length Petal.Width Sepal.Length Sepal.Width
#>    <fctr>        <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl>
#> 1  setosa          1.4         0.2          5.1         3.5
#> 2  setosa          1.4         0.2          4.9         3.0
#> 3  setosa          1.3         0.2          4.7         3.2
#> 4  setosa          1.5         0.2          4.6         3.1
#> 5  setosa          1.4         0.2          5.0         3.6
#> 6  setosa          1.7         0.4          5.4         3.9
```

(and as ever, thanks to Jenny Bryan for the `reprex` package)

Comment: Thanks for your great answer Peter

Answer (score 2):

We can do this with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(melt(setDT(dataset, keep.rownames = TRUE), id.var = c("rn", "Species")), rn + Species ~ variable)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer